# Open webpage retrieve token code and close webpage?

Tags: asp.net, url, token

**Is there a quick way to retrieve the token from another page though its url??**

I need to get a token from a webpage and use it in my current page. The user supplies a email address and password

Example user entry:

> Email: bob@bobby.com
>
> Password: bob

Then i enter it into this link below.

http://formbase.formmobi.com/dvuapi/auth.aspx?email=bob@bobby.com&password=bob

I want to retrieve the token code and return it to my webpage.

[image]

Page source:

```
<result>
  <error number="201" description="Success" />
  <token>6fb29eza-8561-4091-bef0-c81f20c90490</token>
  <expired>False</expired>
  <accounttype>formmobi</accounttype>
  <subscriptionlevel>Premium</subscriptionlevel>
</result>
```

**What would be the most efficient way of retrieving this token value?**

Answer (score 1):

if it is cross domain you will need a proxy file on your end to call the url with a server side language and parse the xml.

You can easily make a cross domain javascript call with jquery, ajax, and jsonp dataType.  But since this response is xml (not jsonp), it probably won't work.